# Customising the Devise :authenticate_user filter to also check for auth tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to be able to customize the :authenticate_user filter to include authenticating a user through an authentication token. The reason I don't want to use the built-in token mechanism is because that allows for only a single auth-token. I want the user to have multiple tokens. Devise as far as I know does not support this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a Strategy of my own to fix this:

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:tokens_authenticatable) do 
  def valid? 
    # code here to check whether to try and authenticate using this strategy; 
    return params.key? :token
  end 

  def authenticate! 
    # code here for doing authentication;
    puts params

    token = Token.where(["token = ?", params[:token]]).first
    puts token
    if (!token.nil?)      
      # if successful, call  
      success!(token.user) # where resource is the whatever you've authenticated, e.g. user;
    else
      # if fail, call 
      fail!("WWAAAAA") # where message is the failure message 
    end
  end 
end

config.warden do |manager|
  # manager.intercept_401 = false
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :tokens_authenticatable
end
```